# SQL query finding all artists with two roles in same play?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to find the artists who have played two characters in the same play; show the title of each such play, name of the artist and the two characters
Also, I can't use group by.
Here are the tables:

```
Plays(Playid,Title,Director,Year,Cost)
Artists(Artistid,Name,Gender,Birthdate)
Roles(Playid,Artistid,Character)
```

and here is what I have so far:

```
select title, a.name, p.playid, r.character, a.artistid 
   from plays p 
   left join roles r on p.playid = r.playid 
   left join artists a on r.artistid = a.artistid;
```

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: we haven't learned it yet so therefore cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select p.title, a.name, r.character, r2.character
from roles r join roles r2 on (r.artistid = r2.artistid and 
                               r.playid = r2.playid and 
                               r.character < r2.character)
left join plays p on r.playid = p.playid
left join artists a on r.artistid = a.artistid
```

Comment: What do you get when you run the query?

Answer (score 0):

add the following:

where a.Artistid in 
(
select Artistid
from Roles
group by Artistid
having count(*) = 2
)

Comment: That query would select all artists who had ever had two roles, regardless of play.

Answer (score 0):

PLease check my query:

```
      Select a.Name,p.Title,r.Character from (select * from Artist where Artistid in
        (select Artistid from Role group by aid having count(rl.Character)>=2)) a 
        left join Role r on r.Artistid=a.Artistid
        left join Play p on r.Playid=p.Playid;
```